# How to re-run solver.solve(planningProblem) again based on current exsting planningProblem?

Tags: optaplanner

If solver.solve(planningProblem) was done, there is one plan to re-run solver.solve(planningProblem) again based on current exsting  planningProblem.

for examples,

```
// run solver.solve first time
solver.solve(planningProblem);
// do some changes, like set newPlanningWindowStart to two days later
...
// run solver.solve second time
solver.solve(planningProblem);
```

but the issue is that, after second time run solver.solve(planningProblem), the ShiftAssignmentList was changed unexpectedly, the first two days shiftAssignment was null. Seems, it just solved the planningProblem again from beginning, instead of based on current existing planningProblem.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Did someone run into this similar situation before? There is no update on this question, seems no one run into this question before...

Comment: Running solve() multiple times on the same problem is fully supported. A more advanced form is called real-time planning & continuous planning, see docs chapter on that.

Comment: Thanks  Geoffrey for your direction. Will find the chapter in the document first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to call `getBestSolution()` after the first `solve()` and use that instance in the second `solve()` call.

Comment: Will give it one more try, and thanks Geoffrey for your suggestions.